# Appendices environment which exceeds 26 in total

Tags: sectioning, counters, appendices

When I inserted the following code as usual, I encountered an error message in the `.aux` file.

```
\begin{subappendices}
\section{Working Diary}
\subsection{09/01/2017}
I have an error today.
\section{Selected Readings and their Reviews}
\section{Connections to Other Topics}
\section{Documentations}
\end{subappendices}
```

In my file, I have 26 of these subappendices. I have compiled Which the error message reads:

```
 \@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{Appendix \numberline {84.A}Working Diary}{392}{section.\protect \begingroup \immediate \write \@unused   \def \MessageBreak  
 \let \protect \edef  You've lost some text.  Try typing  <return>  to proceed.\MessageBreak If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.  \errhelp \let \def \MessageBreak  
            \def   \errmessage  LaTeX Error: Counter too large.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help   \endgroup .84.A}}
```

So when I deleted the use of `hyperref` then everything is fine. Otherwise, using not over 26 appendices is fine as well. However, this is not fruitful to my document.

## MWE

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{morewrites}
\usepackage[toc,title,titletoc]{appendix} % Appendices added
\renewcommand{\appendixname}{Appendix}
\usepackage{etoc}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\let\tableofcontents\etoctableofcontents
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\part{Part A}
\chapter{Dummy}
\localtableofcontents
\begin{subappendices}
\section{Working Diary}
\end{subappendices}
\chapter{The Road to Prove Formally}
\localtableofcontents
\begin{subappendices}
\section{Working Diary}
\end{subappendices}
\chapter{Logical Statements}
\localtableofcontents
\begin{subappendices}
\section{Working Diary}
\end{subappendices}
\chapter{Logical Quantifiers}
\localtableofcontents
\begin{subappendices}
\section{Working Diary}
\end{subappendices}
\chapter{Propositional Calculus}
\begin{subappendices}
\section{Working Diary}
\end{subappendices}
\chapter{Natural Deduction}
\localtableofcontents
\begin{subappendices}
\section{Working Diary}
\end{subappendices}
\chapter{Direct Proof}
\localtableofcontents
\begin{subappendices}
\section{Working Diary}
\end{subappendices}
\chapter{Contrapositive Methods}
\localtableofcontents
\begin{subappendices}
\section{Working Diary}
\end{subappendices}
\chapter{Naive Sets}
\localtableofcontents
\begin{subappendices}
\section{Documentations}
\end{subappendices}
\chapter{Set Operations}
\localtableofcontents
\begin{subappendices}
\section{Working Diary}
\end{subappendices}
\chapter{Relations}
\localtableofcontents
\begin{subappendices}
\section{Working Diary}
\subsection{Binary Relation}
\end{subappendices}
\chapter{Functions}
\localtableofcontents
\chapter{Partial Order}
\begin{subappendices}
\section{Working Diary}
\end{subappendices}
\chapter{Equivalent Relations}
\localtableofcontents
\begin{subappendices}
\section{Working Diary}
\end{subappendices}
\chapter{Combinatorial Principles}
\localtableofcontents
\begin{subappendices}
\section{Working Diary}
\end{subappendices}
\chapter{Enumering Order of Lists}
\localtableofcontents
\begin{subappendices}
\section{Working Diary}
\end{subappendices}
\chapter{Integer Arithmetic}
\localtableofcontents
\begin{subappendices}
\section{Documentations}
\end{subappendices}
\chapter{Algebra on the Complex Set}
\localtableofcontents
\begin{subappendices}
\section{Working Diary}
\end{subappendices}
\chapter{Functions in the Complex Set}
\localtableofcontents
\begin{subappendices}
\section{Documentations}
\end{subappendices}
\chapter{Theory of Probability}
\localtableofcontents
\begin{subappendices}
\section{Working Diary}
\end{subappendices}
\chapter{Bayesian Inference}
\localtableofcontents
\begin{subappendices}
\section{Documentations}
\end{subappendices}
\chapter{Random Variables and Their Distribution}
\localtableofcontents
\begin{subappendices}
\section{Working Diary}
\end{subappendices}
\chapter{Some Chapters}
\localtableofcontents
\begin{subappendices}
\section{Working Diary}
\end{subappendices}
\chapter{Quantum Mechanics is the Holistic Physics}
\begin{subappendices}
\section{Working Diary}
\end{subappendices}
\chapter{Wave-particle Duality}
\localtableofcontents
\begin{subappendices}
\section{Working Diary}
\end{subappendices}
\chapter{Properties of Schroedinger's Equation}
\localtableofcontents
\begin{subappendices}
\section{Working Diary}
\end{subappendices}
\chapter{Acousto-optics}
\localtableofcontents
\begin{subappendices}
\section{Working Diary}
\end{subappendices}
\chapter{Proteins}
\localtableofcontents
\begin{subappendices}
\section{Documentations}
\end{subappendices}
\end{document}
```

Based on this MWE, how to make a document having more than 26 appendices?

Comment: The error seems to be the `appendix` -- it's the usual `counter value to large` error when `\Alph` or `\alph` is used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause of the problem is that the `appendix` package uses a `@pps` counter which is meant to distinguish individual subappendices for `hyperref` usage and defines the hyperanchor `\theH@pps` as `\alph{@pps}`, which must fail after `@pps` reaches the value of 26 (there are only 26 letters in the normal latin alphabet.)

A possible solution is to redefine `\theH@pps` and using `\AlphAlph` (or `\alphalph` from `alphalph` package which allows for `A...Z,AA,AB,....` etc counting.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{morewrites}

\usepackage{alphalph}
\usepackage[toc,title,titletoc]{appendix} % Appendices added

\renewcommand{\appendixname}{Appendix}
\usepackage{etoc}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \renewcommand{\theH@pps}{\AlphAlph{\value{@pps}}}% changing the hyperanchors
}
\makeatother
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\let\tableofcontents\etoctableofcontents
\usepackage{hyperref}



\begin{document}
\part{Part A}
\chapter{Dummy}
\localtableofcontents
\begin{subappendices}
\section{Working Diary}
\end{subappendices}
\chapter{The Road to Prove Formally}
\localtableofcontents
\begin{subappendices}
\section{Working Diary}
\end{subappendices}
\chapter{Logical Statements}
\localtableofcontents
\begin{subappendices}
\section{Working Diary}
\end{subappendices}
\chapter{Logical Quantifiers}
\localtableofcontents
\begin{subappendices}
\section{Working Diary}
\end{subappendices}
\chapter{Propositional Calculus}
\begin{subappendices}
\section{Working Diary}
\end{subappendices}
\chapter{Natural Deduction}
\localtableofcontents
\begin{subappendices}
\section{Working Diary}
\end{subappendices}
\chapter{Direct Proof}
\localtableofcontents
\begin{subappendices}
\section{Working Diary}
\end{subappendices}
\chapter{Contrapositive Methods}
\localtableofcontents
\begin{subappendices}
\section{Working Diary}
\end{subappendices}
\chapter{Naive Sets}
\localtableofcontents
\begin{subappendices}
\section{Documentations}
\end{subappendices}
\chapter{Set Operations}
\localtableofcontents
\begin{subappendices}
\section{Working Diary}
\end{subappendices}
\chapter{Relations}
\localtableofcontents
\begin{subappendices}
\section{Working Diary}
\subsection{Binary Relation}
\end{subappendices}
\chapter{Functions}
\localtableofcontents
\chapter{Partial Order}
\begin{subappendices}
\section{Working Diary}
\end{subappendices}
\chapter{Equivalent Relations}
\localtableofcontents
\begin{subappendices}
\section{Working Diary}
\end{subappendices}
\chapter{Combinatorial Principles}
\localtableofcontents
\begin{subappendices}
\section{Working Diary}
\end{subappendices}
\chapter{Enumering Order of Lists}
\localtableofcontents
\begin{subappendices}
\section{Working Diary}
\end{subappendices}
\chapter{Integer Arithmetic}
\localtableofcontents
\begin{subappendices}
\section{Documentations}
\end{subappendices}
\chapter{Algebra on the Complex Set}
\localtableofcontents
\begin{subappendices}
\section{Working Diary}
\end{subappendices}
\chapter{Functions in the Complex Set}
\localtableofcontents
\begin{subappendices}
\section{Documentations}
\end{subappendices}
\chapter{Theory of Probability}
\localtableofcontents
\begin{subappendices}
\section{Working Diary}
\end{subappendices}
\chapter{Bayesian Inference}
\localtableofcontents
\begin{subappendices}
\section{Documentations}
\end{subappendices}
\chapter{Random Variables and Their Distribution}
\localtableofcontents
\begin{subappendices}
\section{Working Diary}
\end{subappendices}
\chapter{Some Chapters}
\localtableofcontents
\begin{subappendices}
\section{Working Diary}
\end{subappendices}
\chapter{Quantum Mechanics is the Holistic Physics}
\begin{subappendices}
\section{Working Diary}
\end{subappendices}
\chapter{Wave-particle Duality}
\localtableofcontents
\begin{subappendices}
\section{Working Diary}
\end{subappendices}
\chapter{Properties of Schroedinger's Equation}
\localtableofcontents
\begin{subappendices}
\section{Working Diary}
\end{subappendices}
\chapter{Acousto-optics}
\localtableofcontents
\begin{subappendices}
\section{Working Diary}
\end{subappendices}
\chapter{Proteins}
\localtableofcontents
\begin{subappendices}
\section{Documentations}
\end{subappendices}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I omitted a screen shot since it does not reveal anything here

Comment: @SHY.John: Compiling twice is clear, I think ;-) Happy TeXing!